# How to select spans under one div but not another via XPath?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

Say I have this page:

```
<div class="top">
    <span class="strings">asdf</span>
    <span class="strings">qwer</span>
    <span class="strings">zxcv</span>
</div>

<div id="content">
some other text
    <span class="strings">1234</span>
    <span class="strings">5678</span>
    <span class="strings">1234</span>
</div>
```

How do I get the script to only scrape the `span` class strings in the `div` `id="content"`, **not** `div` `class="top"`? Results should be '1234', '5678', '1234'.

Here is my code so far:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = 'http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00SGGQRNO'
response = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
bullets = tree.xpath('//span[@class="strings"]/text()')
print ('Bullets: ',bullets)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select only the text of those `span` elements (with `@class="strings"`) that are children of the `div` element with `@id="content`, use this XPath expression:

```
//div[@id="content"]/span[@class="strings"]/text()
```